# Adding a specific Fontawesome icon on Woocommece tab titles

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs

I'm trying to add a custom fontawesome icon on each of my Woocommerce tabs, you know, the ones in the product pages : Description / Additional information / Reviews.

I tried something like this :

```
 li.additional_information_tab::before {
  content: "\f005"; 
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

I'm expecting to get the icon (one specific icon for each tab title) to be displayed right before the tab title, but the icon displays on a line, and the tab title on the line after, I'm pretty sure I'm not doing it right, would someone have some idea about that ?

Comment: It's probably to do with spacing.  If the tabs are tight enough and have a width setting then the icon and text may force a wrap.  You'd need to include a bit more code and perhaps add some CSS to the tabs themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following jQuery code instead:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'custom_single_product_js' );
function custom_single_product_js(){
    ?><script>jQuery(function($){
        $('li.additional_information_tab a').prepend('<i class="fa fa-star"></i> ');
    });</script><?php
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Ohhh ! Works sooo well, thanks a million !! 